# Redshift cannot insert, timestamp column is of type string

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift, sql-insert

I have two tables in redshift that are exact copies of each other, (scans, scans_staging), one is a staging table and the other is the main table. they have the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE scans_staging (
    id text,
    imb text,
    scandatetime timestamp without time zone,
    scaneventcode text,
    status text,
    anticipateddeliverydate timestamp without time zone,
    scanfacilityname text,
    scanfacilitystate text,
    scanfacilitycity text,
    scanfacilityzip text
);
```

and I am trying to run a query to upsert data from the staging table to the scans table, like so:

```
insert into scans
select scans_staging.*
from scans
right join scans_staging on scans.id = scans_staging.id
where scans.id is null
```

However I get the error: `Invalid operation: column "scandatetime" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying`

but when I look at the data in both tables, the timestamps are exactly the same format, `2020-11-23 16:17:02`, for example. They are in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. What rookie mistake am I making here?

EDIT: Here is the result of the following table def query:

```
select "column", type, encoding, distkey, sortkey, "notnull" 
from pg_table_def
where tablename = 'scans'
```

for both tables

```
Scans:

|column                 |type                       |encoding|distkey|sortkey  |notnull|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id                     |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|imb                    |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|scandatetime           |timestamp without time zone|az64    |false  |0        |false  |
|scaneventcode          |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|status                 |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|anticipateddeliverydate|timestamp without time zone|az64    |false  |0        |false  |
|scanfacilityname       |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|scanfacilitystate      |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|scanfacilitycity       |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|scanfacilityzip        |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |

Scans_staging:

|column                 |type                       |encoding|distkey|sortkey  |notnull|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id                     |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|imb                    |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|scandatetime           |timestamp without time zone|az64    |false  |0        |false  |
|scaneventcode          |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|status                 |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|anticipateddeliverydate|timestamp without time zone|az64    |false  |0        |false  |
|scanfacilityname       |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|scanfacilitystate      |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|scanfacilitycity       |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
|scanfacilityzip        |character varying(256)     |lzo     |false  |0        |false  |
```

Comment: May not be the issue but for inserts and selects you should specify the columns and not use select *  (or leave the columns list blank for insert into the table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not get that error if the structure of both tables was exactly the same.

I would start by enumerating the columns in the `insert` and `select` clause to avoid a potential problem with columns not appearing in the same position in both tables:

```
insert into scans (
       id, imb, scandatetime, scaneventcode, status, anticipateddeliverydate, scanfacilityname, scanfacilitystate, scanfacilitycity, scanfacilityzip
)
select id, imb, scandatetime, scaneventcode, status, anticipateddeliverydate, scanfacilityname, scanfacilitystate, scanfacilitycity, scanfacilityzip
from scans_staging ss
where not exists  (select 1 from scans s where s.id = ss.id)
```

If you still get a type mismatch error, this indicates that you have columns that have different datatypes. If so, you need to set up additional casting in the `select` clause.

Comment: Hi, can you look at the update I just made wrt table definitions to see if that matters?

Comment: @DBA108642: ok, so it looks like the datatypes do align. This does not show the ordering of columns in the table though. What happens when you try the query I provided in my answer?

Comment: im running it now, and it hasn't error yet so I take it that's a good sign. it may have done the trick

Comment: confirmed that your query worked. Thanks!